# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "th:replace" associated with an element type "tr" must not contain the '<' character

Tags: html, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

```
<tr th:replace="textbox1 :: textbox1”></tr>
```

is producing this error

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "th:replace" associated with an element type "tr" must not contain the '<' character.
```

What could be causing this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `”` to `"` like following;)

```
<tr th:replace="textbox1 :: textbox1"></tr>
```